# Error with shell scripting

Tags: shell

```
!#/bin/bash

  svnadmin dump /path/to/repo | gzip -9 > /path/to/backup.bak-$(date     +"%d\%m\%Y--%T").dump.gz
if ( `echo $?` -eq 0) 
then
    echo "hello world" | mail -s "a subject" someone@wherever.com
else
    echo "sorry, no way out" | mail -s "a subject" someone@wherever.com 
exit 1
fi
```

there is an edit with the question

Any help is appreciated. Thanks
The output i get is the else part " sorry no way out! but what i expect to get is a hello world as the dump command works perfectly

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's the error?

Comment: The edit made by @Allendar deleted the actual question.

Comment: @BalusC point noted:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `IF` clause should be: `if [ $? -eq 0 ]`. Notice the square brackets and the whitespaces around them.

Comment: Actually, it should be `if [ $? -eq 0 ]`.  No need for the `echo`.

Comment: thanks @adrianp It worked ! :) 


!#/bin/bash
ls ;

if [ $? -eq 0 ]

Comment: Actually `cmd; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...` should almost always be rewritten `if cmd; then ...`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it:

```
 !#/bin/bash 

 ls;
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your shebang is wrong.  It should be `#!`.  Also,
do not bother explicitly checking `$?`.  Just do:

```
if ls; then
      ...
else
      ...
fi
```

Comment: Hi, I prefer using the same structure. What happens now is, even though the ls command works , i get the else part message to my mail.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same structure"?  Do you mean the one with incorrect syntax?

Comment: actually i have some command for svnbackup and i want to execute this mailing script only when that command is a sucess

svnadmin dump /path/to/repo/ | gzip -9 > /path/to/backup-$(date +"%d\%m\%Y--%T").dump.gz

Comment: @rahul:  You can just as easily do `if svnadmin dump ... | gzip ...; then` and get things to work rather than using a syntax that does not work.  It would seem that a syntax which works is preferable to one that does not!  (Although in this case whether either works is dependent on `gzip` providing a return value for `svnadmin`, which it will not.)